# Selecting an image inside of TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview, collectionview

I have a tableView, and inside of that tableView are 3 images.

I would like to be able to select an image and be directed to another VC where it displays the image that has been tapped.

For my images (downloaded from Parse) I have a uuid (unique identifier), before when I was using a collectionView I set it up like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        postuuid.append(uuidArray[indexPath.row])

        let post = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("collectionImage") as! CollectionImageViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)
    }
```

And that got me what I am trying to achieve now...

I realized I cannot use TableView SelectedRow..... as that would select the entire row obviously, so I have set up a image UITapGestureRecognized like so:

```
 let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTap")
            imageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
```

And then a func() to redirect it to a new VC:

```
 func imageTap() {

        postuuid.append// My issues here, I'm not sure how to set it up or reference it to the cellForRow, like I did it in the collectionViewSelected item code above.

        let post = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("collectionImage") as! CollectionImageViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)
    }
```

As you'll see from my code I do not know, or can't seem to figure it out at the moment, how to connect it to the unique ID...

I have the UUID set up as var = uuidArray = String which is downloading them correctly...

CellForRow...:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
        var counter = (indexPath.row * 3)

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! ProfileTableViewCell




        for imageView in cell.threeImages {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceHolder")

            if counter < imageArray.count {
            imageView.hidden = false
            let finalImage = imageArray[counter++]["image"]
            finalImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        imageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)

                    }}}} else {
                imageView.hidden = true
            }



           let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTap")
            imageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)


return cell
        }
```

If anyone can help me with this issue, I thank you very much in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: can you show your cellfor rowatindexpath, it is easy to resolve

Comment: you also can use UIButton that also usefull and you also get its event too.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have updated it

Comment: @NitinGohel I know, but I would prefer to try and do it this way first!

Comment: Why can't you select the row?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Because that would select all three images inside the Row/cell.

Comment: Oh, why not put them in separate rows/cells? Or are they all related somehow?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace Three different images in 1 cell, and I like them in 1 row (Design issues) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add indexPath.row as the tag for the tapGesture recognizer:

```
...
let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "imageTap:")
imageView.tag = indexPath.row
...
```

and setup your function as

```
func imageTap(sender:AnyObject) {

    postuuid.append(uuidArray[sender.view.tag])

    let post = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("collectionImage") as! CollectionImageViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(post, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It's not letting me add tag..?

Comment: sorry my bad, you cant add tag to the gesture but you can add tag to the imageView and can access it later as sender.view.tag